# restoring mariadb using sqldump generated sql file throw errorcode 22

Tags: mysql, backup, mariadb, restore

I run the following to dump full database
C:\MariaDB\bin mysqldump.exe -uroot -p --single-transaction --flush-logs --master-data=2  --all-databases > full_db_backup.sql
on one computer.

Then, on another machine, I reinstall a fresh new MariaDB 10.1.22. And populate this new database instance with the following:
C:\MariaDB\bin mysql.exe -uroot -p < full_db_backup.sql

After running for half a hour, I get the following error
mysql.exe: Error reading file '' (Errcode: 22 "Invalid argument")

This error even does not have enough information for me to debug or chase down. The sql dump is 90GB and pretty large. It is hopeless to grep '' from that file. I even have no idea how to start to investigate this problem. By the way, both original database instance and new database instance are MariaDB 10.1.22.

Comment: Which MariaDB Version have you installed on the old server where you start the mysqldump ?

Comment: One option is to export it into multiple files (ie do partial backups/reloads) - to narrow the error down to a certain part of the backup.

Comment: As the last sentence in the question indicates, both original database instance and new database instance are MariaDB 10.1.22. Thanks.

Comment: I run mysqldump on the old server to generate the full_db_backup.sql file and run "mysql.exe -uroot -p < full_db_backup.sql" on the new server which is freshly installed.  The file full_db_backup.sql is in a NAS device (synology datastation) which is accessible to both server through mapped drive.

Answer (score 0):

1) I run "chkdsk /F"
2) reboot my computer
3) run "C:\MariaDB\bin mysql.exe -uroot -p < full_db_backup.sql" 
Now, it works. My speculation is that is something related to hardware. ErrorCode 22 might not be an MariaDB error code at all. It is some OS errorcode passed to MariaDB. I tried 2) and 3) a few times before, it does NOT work.  So "chkdsk /F"
is the magic here.